# My Code refuses to run properly because of "initialization errors"

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, output

My Code refuses to run properly because of "initialization errors" & second switch running on to errors. I made an `Double` array `Payroll`. Unfortunately, the compiler keeps on telling me that it is not being initialized; but I have an array that the does not pick it up.

```
package myNewPayroll;

import java.util.*;

class Payroll {
    //employeeID, employeeName, employeeRate 

    static String[][] Employee = {{"101", "Alex", "50"}, {"102", "Bethany", "100"}, {"103", "Clarence", "200"}};

//RHW = 8
//HW = 8
//HW = 9
//OTP = 10%
    static void print_data() {
        System.out.println("ID\t Name \tRate");
        for (int RID = 0; RID < Employee.length; RID++) {
            for (int CID = 0; RID < Employee[RID].length; CID++) {
                System.out.print(Employee[RID][CID]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static int search(String empID) {
        int EID = -1;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < Employee.length; idx++) {
            if (Employee[idx][0].equals(empID)) {
                EID = idx;
            }
        }
        return EID;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int HoursWorked;
        String EmpID;
        int choice;
        int RowHoursWorked;
        do {
            System.out.println("[1] Receive Payroll");
            System.out.println("[2] Update Profile");
            System.out.println("[3] Change Rate");
            System.out.println("[4] Exit");

            choice = sc.nextInt();
            int RowID;

            if (choice > 1 && choice < 3) {
                print_data();
                System.out.println("Enter Employee ID: ");
                EmpID = sc.next();
                RowID = search(EmpID);

            }
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Input Hours Worked: ");
                    HoursWorked = sc.nextInt();
                    int rate = Integer.parseInt(Employee[RowID][2]);
                    double salary = 0;
                    String Remarks = "Overtime";
                    if (HoursWorked > RowHoursWorked) {
                        double OTP = rate * 0.10;
                        int OT = HoursWorked - RowHoursWorked;
                        OTP = OT * OTP;
                        salary = RowHoursWorked * 8;
                    } else {
                        if (HoursWorked == 0) {
                            Remarks = "Absent";
                        } else if (HoursWorked == RowHoursWorked) {
                            Remarks = "Regular";
                        } else {
                            Remarks = "Undertime";
                        }
                        salary = HoursWorked * rate;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Salary = " + salary);
                    System.out.println("Remarks = " + Remarks);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < Employee[RowID].length; idx++) {
                        System.out.println("Input Data");
                        Employee[RowID][idx] = sc.next();
                    }
                    print_data();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Enter New Rate: ");
                    Employee[RowID][2] = sc.next();
                    print_data();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input! Try Again!");
                    break;
            }

        } while (choice != 4);
    }
}
```

I tried initializing, and it is not getting me the results I want. When I typed 1, it only gets me the numbers based on the initialized values, not without them. When I typed 2, I get an error.

Comment: My compiler says that `RowHoursWorked` and `RowID` "might not have been initialized." What happens if you initialize them?

Comment: Then, critically examine the the inner loop of `printData()` and ask why it examines the row id when looping over columns.